# What's the difference between envy and resent?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between envy and resent?

**envy**

> painful or resentful awareness of an advantage enjoyed by another joined with a desire to possess the same advantage

> Envy is the feeling you have when you wish you could have the same thing or quality that someone else has.

> If you envy someone, you wish that you had the same things or qualities that they have.

**resent**

> If you resent someone or something, you feel bitter and angry about them. [[source]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/resent)

> to feel bitter or angry about something, especially because you feel it is unfair [[source]](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/resent?q=resent)

---

However the word resent is used as a comparative emotion [as this article says](https://www.intentionalcommunication.com/envy-jealousy-resentment-the-comparison-emotions-at-work-reprise/). It is often used interchangeably with the word **envy**, so maybe there is a modern meaning in our current lexicon that the dictionary fails to explain, where they can both used in the same place.

Comment: Envy is (or is close to being) a hyponym.

Comment: The noun is _resentment_.

Answer (score 5):

As your definitions highlight, envy typically involves resentment. However, it specifically includes some degree of jealousy - it's resentment towards someone *because* they have something of perceived value.

Resentment is more general term and can be motivated by pretty much any reason. For example, getting into an accident with a drunk driver might make you feel resentful but I can't imagine you would feel envious.

You could probably argue that all envious people are resentful (overlooking the motivation) but you can't say that every resentful person is envious.